# How do you fetch a json from nodejs server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-cloud-datastore

Below is the front end with react and the backend with nodejs/expresjs. I can correctly get the data to the backend but when I try to download the data to my front end it constantly gives me a

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data[Learn More]"

But I have used a similar format prior and had no issues. Can anyone give me any advice on the issue?

Thank you!

frontend

```
import React from 'react';

export default () => {
  let images = fetch('http://localhost:3000/datastore', {
    mode: "no-cors", // no-cors, cors, *same-origin
    cache: "no-cache", // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
    credentials: "same-origin", // include, same-origin, *omit
  })
  .then(response => response.json());

  console.log(images);

  images.forEach((u, i) => {
    console.log(images[i])
  });

  return <div>

  </div>
}
```

backend

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
let Datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore')
const datastore = Datastore();
const query = datastore.createQuery('image');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next){
  datastore
  .runQuery(query)
  .then(results => {
    let tasks = results[0];
    console.log('Tasks:');
    tasks.forEach(task => {
        const taskKey = task[datastore.KEY];
        console.log(taskKey.id, task);
    });
    console.log(tasks);
    return res.send(tasks);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err);
    return res.status(200).send({
        success: false
    });
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: What does the endpoint JSON look like?

Comment: also it looks like tasks goes from an array of `object`s to a `string` randomly?

Comment: I had it as an object before and it still gave me the same error

Comment: navigate to/curl `http://localhost:3000/datastore` and paste the response in your question, please.

Comment: i get the following when i curl
[{"user":"joeshmo","description":["face","facial expression","head","facial hair","gentleman","collage","smile"],"image_address":"....","translation":["面对","表情","头","胡子","绅士","大学","微笑"]},....]

Comment: Why not post what you get back when you get the error?!

Comment: as in post back from the front-end to the back-end?

Comment: As in show what's happening on the network when it fails.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: ?! You look in the network tab and see?

Comment: Okay I did that and it gives me a 200 OK status which I'm assuming means there are no errors?

Comment: It means the status was 200 (which you return if there's an error for some reason), check the data: what you're parsing. We can't see anything on your end; we don't even know exactly where the error is occurring.

Comment: The back-end is sending an array of dictionaries with res.send() I don't have any views or html page included its just sending the array

Comment: But presumably you have a browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was actually in the back-end. I didn't allow cross origin

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
let Datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore')
const datastore = Datastore();
const query = datastore.createQuery('image');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next){
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS');

  datastore
  .runQuery(query)
  .then(results => {
    let tasks = results[0];
    console.log('Tasks:');
    tasks.forEach(task => {
      const taskKey = task[datastore.KEY];
      console.log(taskKey.id, task);
    });
    console.log(tasks);
    return res.send(tasks);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err);
      return res.status(200).send({
      success: false
    });
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Tyler Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/877279/tyler-sebastian) answer in full. But let me explain it. Whenever u call api using **fetch** It return **Promise** it is basically async so it like "calling api and waiting for it response". So

```
let images = fetch('http://localhost:3000/datastore', {
    mode: "no-cors", // no-cors, cors, *same-origin
    cache: "no-cache", // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
    credentials: "same-origin", // include, same-origin, *omit
});
```

This line images is **Promise** Object. 
When u call **.then** on it. It will response you when it finished fetching data from backend.

```
let images = fetch('http://localhost:3000/datastore', {  
    mode: "no-cors", // no-cors, cors, *same-origin
    cache: "no-cache", // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
    credentials: "same-origin", // include, same-origin, *omit
}).then(response => response.json()); //1 This line of code
console.log(images); // 2 and this line of code
```

Line number 6 maybe execute before line number 5. I suggest you to read **Promise**,
**asynchronous code** before. 
Here is better way to do that.

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/datastore', {  
     mode: "no-cors", // no-cors, cors, *same-origin
     cache: "no-cache", // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
     credentials: "same-origin", // include, same-origin, *omit
}).then(response => {
   printImages(response); //Note that this is not your data, images array will be deep down in response.response.data
}); 
printResponse = (response) => { 
   console.log(response);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have concerns about your API endpoint... See my comments.

Regarding the component:

`fetch` is asynchronous - `images` is a *`Promise`*, not the actually response from the endpoint. You need to use component state

```
class Component extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/datastore', {
      mode: "no-cors", // no-cors, cors, *same-origin
      cache: "no-cache", // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
      credentials: "same-origin", // include, same-origin, *omit
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(images => this.setState({ images });
  }

  render () {
    const { images } = this.state // use this
    return <div> ... </div>
  }
}
```

again this all assumes that the endpoint returns valid JSON.

Comment: This only organizes my file better but doesn't answer my main question :(
I'm asking how do I send the array from my back-end to my front-end

Comment: Please refer to my comments.

Comment: So I changed my file this way and it still didn't send the array to the front-end

Comment: Well yes, because the backend is return invalid JSON.

Comment: then how come when I curl it it returns the JSON?